# overlay histogram by certain order of fill color

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using geom_histogram in ggplot and position = "identity" is it possible to choose the order of which color goes first?

```
a <- data.frame(rep(1:10, each = 4))
b <- data.frame(rep(1:3, each = 5))
c <- data.frame(rep(4:9, each = 3))
names(a) <- "num"
names(b) <- "num"
names(c) <- "num"
a$color <- "red"
b$color <- "white"
c$color <- "blue"

abc <- rbind(a,b,c)

ggplot() + geom_histogram(data = abc, aes(x=num, fill = color),
position = "identity") + scale_fill_identity()
```

Is it possible to plot white, then red then blue?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways

```
## Make color a factor
abc$color <- as.factor(abc$color)  # "blue"  "red"   "white"

## Using desc to reverse order in aes
ggplot() + geom_histogram(data = abc, aes(x=num, fill = color, order=desc(color)),
                          position = "identity") + scale_fill_identity()

## Manually reorder factors
abc$color <- with(abc, factor(color, levels(abc$color)[3:1]))
ggplot() + geom_histogram(data = abc, aes(x=num, fill = color),
                          position = "identity") + scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]